# Modify or Delete Data in a File

Tags: java, file, file-io

Today I was trying the algorithm for modifying and deleting data inside a file using Java in Windows platform.

1st : create a temporaryFile
2nd : write the data you wanted inside the originalFile into a String and to the temporaryFile
3rd : rename temporaryFile to originalFile.

#### The Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class testing{
    private static String temp;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try{
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("haha\\temporary", ".txt");         //create a temporary file in haha folder
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("haha\\testing.txt")); //get input from testing.txt
        temp = input.next();
        writer.write(temp);
        writer.close();
        File origFile = new File("haha\\testing.txt");
        tempFile.renameTo(origFile);
        }
        catch ( FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException ){}
        catch(IOException ioException){}
    }
}
```

In the above code , the textFile to be edited is located inside a folder name `haha` which is located inside another folder together with the `testing.class`.I've tried this code to no avail , the originalTextFile has no changes .

Comment: Why don't you **remove the empty catch blocks** to see the exception message?!

Comment: Warning: `.renameTo()` returns a boolean. Unfortunately so. Also, `File` has `.createTempFile()` to create temporary files, you could use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your file in the same directory, you don't need to pass the path to the File constructor.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("testing.txt"));
```

This should do it.

Comment: as i said it's not in the same directory with the class file but it's in a folder name haha which is in the same folder with class file

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the Scanner object to make the changes, the underlying operating system has a file lock that must be released.

```
     input.close();
     File origFile = new File("haha\\testing.txt");
```